# Store object dynamically in object

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question might sound stupid or a little too simple but I seriously got stuck.

I have a node.js app and need to store clients to be able to send information from a specific client to a specific other client.

```
var clients = { };

var chat     = io.of('/chat')
.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket
    .on('ehlo', function(data) {
        // mysql queries here etc to get client's data,
        // for example session_id, customer name, ...

        // got stuck here, need to save the socket in customers object like:
        clients.(customer + data.get_customer_id) = { socket: socket };
```

I later need to be able to access this property from a different scope etc.

Basically I lack an idea of how these abstract methods can be implemented:

```
clients.addClient({ id: 123, socket: socket});
```

And later find them by:

```
x = clients.findById(123);
// x now should be { id: 123, socket: socket}
```

Comment: So.... You want a database?

Comment: If adding and finding by Id all you want you can do `var clients = Object.create(null); clients[123] = socket; /* added client */; clients[123]; /* returns the socket */` Note this is not persistent.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum no no, I just want an object able to hold client objects and return a client object identified by an ID.
I'm confused because Javascript arrays have functions like `find()`, and `push()`, but to use `find()` for example, I have to foreach like every element. Not sure whether this is good.

Comment: Which is why I a suggested a database, which would index that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I just want the clients to be held during runtime and dropped when the app closes. I don't want to query the database for each emitted event. Thanks tho, your second comment gave me an idea, along with Edwins answer!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum When the app or a client restarts/reconnects, the `clients` array/object is going to get re-populated from my database. But during runtime, I only want to query the database about changes, not query mysql for every emitted event.

Comment: Hmm, what about redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can define a clients module first.

```
//clients.js
"use strict";

var clients = {
    _db: []
};

clients.findById = function(id){
    for(var i=0; i < this._db.length; i++){
        var client = this._db[i];
        if(client.id === id){
            return client;
        }
    }
    return null;
};

clients.addClient = function(client) {
    if(!this.findById(client.id)){
        this._db.push(client);
    }
};

module.exports = clients;
```

The way Node.js works it will cache your module after it's initialized. This after you use it for the first time. This means that every time you require it, you will get the same `clients` object. So now you can do this in a hypothetical module1.js:

```
//module1.js
var clients = require('./clients');
clients.addClient(newClient);
```

And later in another module you can gain access to the same data structure:

```
//module2.js
var clients = require('./clients');
var client = clients.findById(id);
```

And that's it, you can gain access to your same data structure from different contexts. The point here is that all modules will share the same `clients` object.

Comment: Would I use `this._db.push()` and `this._db.find()` in the functions?

Comment: Sure, if the database of clients is an array you could use push. I do not think node.js arrays have the find function defined. But you can implement your own. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you estimate with how many objects in the _db array, the findById method will start to get slow?

Comment: Well, supposing the array is not sorted (as I did above), than I think this is a linear search. This is an `O(n)` algorithm. As the list grows, so it does the time it needs to find a client. You can improve by using a hash data structure instead in whose case you would reduce lookup time to `O(1)`. You can use the client id as the key. I leave that problem to you.